# Unable to get secrets in Azure pipeline

Tags: azure, azure-devops

I have a python application that needs to access a secret in my Azure pipelines. When the environmental variables are plaintext I have no issue. However once I make it a secret its `******` or `None`. I found this nice [blog](https://brandonsnotepad.wordpress.com/2021/04/23/azure-devops-secret-variables-python/) and it looked very promising but sadly it did not work.

This is how I am setting my secret

```
  - bash: |
      echo "HOST: $(HOST2)"
      echo "PORT: $(PORT2)"
      echo "USERNAME: $(USERNAME2)"
    env:
      HOST: $(HOST2)
      PORT: $(PORT2)
      USERNAME: $(USERNAME2)
      PASSWORD: $(PASSWORD2)
```

Only the host, port and username can be effectively read. I then decided maybe I can create a file, put the password in there and read the file. However the password is `******` in the file as well.

`cat $(PASSWORD2) > password.txt`

Has anyone had this issue and solved it?

update:

Here is the python part where I am trying to get the secret

```
if os.getenv("HOST"):
    P_HOST = os.getenv('HOST')
    P_PORT = os.getenv('PORT')
    P_USERNAME = os.getenv('USERNAME')
    P_PWD = os.getenv('PASSWORD')

print('PASSWORD', PASSWORD)
```

The password is `None`...

Error when trying to connect....

```
TypeError: sequence item 1: expected str instance, NoneType found
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The mentioned [blog](https://brandonsnotepad.wordpress.com/2021/04/23/azure-devops-secret-variables-python/) has shared the solution that you can read the secret from `environment variables`.

I followed your sample and created python script below:

```
import os
import urllib.request

def call_api_xyz(resource):

  host = os.getenv('HOST')
  password = os.getenv('PASSWORD')

  print('DEBUG: The Host is ' + host)
  print('DEBUG: The password is ' + password)
  print('DEBUG: The password is ' + password[0:10])

# Call the function
call_api_xyz('resource')
```

My yaml:

```
- bash: |
    python test.py
  env:
    HOST: $(HOST2)
    PASSWORD: $(PASSWORD2)
```

The output is:

[image]

For Host it's not secret, which can be output fine.

For PASSWORD(value `passtestword`) which is secret:

The first value display as `***` which is **correct behavior** as DevOps will masked it from the output.

The second value display as `passtestwo` since it's only part of the secret, but it proves it can read the secret value from environment.

[image]

Comment: Thank you for you response. However I do have what you posted and get. 
``` 
app/searcher.py:24: in <module>
    print('DEBUG: The password is ' + PASSWORD[0:10])
E   TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable

```

Comment: The script i shared is just a sample about how to read secret from environment. According to the ` 'NoneType' object...` error, please share your python script content for troubleshooting.

Comment: @Mike3355,  you should print `ES_PWD2` in your py script. Fix as this: `print('PASSWORD', ES_PWD2)`. It will print *** as secret is masked from the log.

Comment: Hi @Mike3355, may i know if there's any update, let me know if you have any queires.

Comment: I found a solution. The issue is the issue is secrets are not available in other steps in the template that I have to use. The solution was to run the tests in a `bash | ` and is the tests failed do an exit 1. For now it works and I need to work on the template. In the meantime I will go ahead and except the answer. It might help someone.